# Is it possible to give a box an "overflow: auto" when it's wrapper has "overflow: hidden"?

Tags: css

I have a "close" link and a content box with text inside a absolute positioned wrapper with fixed width and height and `overflow: hidden`. If the text is longer than the height of the wrapper a scrollbar should be applied to the content box.

I tried `overflow: auto` and even `overflow: scroll` but it doesn't work.

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henrik23/mwqq8rzd/29/

I could give the wrapper an `overflow: auto` but that's not what I want. Only the text should be scrollable, the "close" link should stay in place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `.content` to scroll, you can use `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll`. But I suggest giving it some height, e.g. `height:100%` of its parent. Otherwise, the height of `.content` will expand to fit its content (instead of scrolling) and `.wrapper` will cut off the bottom due to its `overflow:hidden`.

```
.content {
    overflow: auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

Test below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.close {
  text-align: right;
}
.content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="close">
    <a href="#">close</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some
      content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

Actually, `height:100%` doesn't quite work. Because the `.close` element takes up some height, `height:100%` pushes the bottom of `.content` past the bottom of `.wrapper`. One solution is to set a height for both `.close` and `.content` so that they both add up to 100%.

```
.close {
  text-align: right;
  height:15%;
}
.content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 85%;
}
```

Test below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.close {
  text-align: right;
  height: 15%;
}
.content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="close">
    <a href="#">close</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some
      content ... This is content ... some content ... This is content ... some content ... END</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That easy :-) ... yes it makes sense to add both heights to get 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You should add height:

```
.content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mwqq8rzd/41/)

Answer (score 0):

Here we go. The css attribute `overflow: auto` works with a defined `height`. Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwqq8rzd/36/)